# React on different subdomains

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, subdomain

I have a folder on my FTP with a React / Nextjs app in /myapp. My url my.app points to that folder.
Is it possible to to add different subdomains (e.g. user1.my.app and user2.my.app) that point to the same folder /myapp. The app detects the subdomain and can set different states based on the subdomains?

Comment: React has nothing to do with domains at all. I guess, your question is relevant to the hosting configuration. So, it depends on a particular web server you use, I guess.

Comment: That’s not true. react-router-dom has to do with URL and I want React to act differently based on the url. I don’t know if a server configuration will solve my issue.

Comment: URL consists of different parts. `<protocol>://<server-name>:<port>/<path>?<query-string>`. Domain is in first part, it has nothing to do with the webpage itself and any router. SPA routers work with `<path>` part of the URL.

Comment: And SPA routers work in the browser page when it's already loaded. But you are saying that different domains should point to the same folder. It's a webserver job.

Comment: This setup is easy. My question aims at how react can detect the domain (subdomain) and do something based on that value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React has nothing to do with domains at all. I guess, your question is relevant to the hosting configuration. So, it depends on a particular web server you use.

---

**URL**

URL consists of different parts: `<scheme>://<user-info>@<subdomain>.<domain>:<port>/<path>?<query-string>#<hash>`.

[image: Diagram made by OmenBreeze - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=82827943]

*Diagram made by OmenBreeze - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0,

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=82827943*

---

**React Router**

Domain has nothing to do with a webpage itself and a router on a webpage. SPA router works with `<path>`, `<query-string>`, and `<hash>` (also known as `<fragment>`) parts of the URL.

> **`location`**
>
> Locations represent where the app is now, where you want it to go, or even where it was. It looks like this:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "key": "ac3df4", // not with HashHistory!
>   "pathname": "/somewhere",
>   "search": "?some=search-string",
>   "hash": "#howdy",
>   "state": undefined
> }
> ```
>
> [React Router Docs: Web > API > location](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location)

SPA router works in the browser page when it's already loaded. But you are saying that different domains should point to the same folder. It's a web server job.

---

**Apache** *(as a web server example)*

In Apache web server you can configure two different virtual hosts to point to the same directory:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     DocumentRoot "/myapp"
>     ServerName user1.my.app
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     DocumentRoot "/myapp"
>     ServerName user2.my.app
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

---

❗ In comments you stated:

> My question aims at how react can detect the domain (subdomain) and do something based on that value.

It's not exactly a React question anyway. It can be addressed with pure JavaScript.

---

✅ **Get current domain in JavaScript and use it in React**

If you want to know what is the domain in the current browser address in JavaScript, you need to use `document.location`.

`document.location.hostname` contains the full domain name from the address URL.

> **`Location`**
>
> The Location interface represents the location (URL) of the object it is linked to. Changes done on it are reflected on the object it relates to. Both the `Document` and `Window` interface have such a linked `Location`, accessible via `Document.location` and `Window.location` respectively.
>
> **`Location.hostname`**
>
> Is a USVString containing the domain of the URL.
>
> [MDN: Web technology for developers > Web APIs > Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

In React you can do it in your root `App` component in its constructor.

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.hostname = document.location.hostname;
    console.log(this.hostname);
  }
}
```